# How to change action bar tab view height

Tags: android

How to customize action bar tab view to have desired height..?

I want the output like this with action bar tabs
[image]

but i am getting the output like this

[image]

I am using custom view on tabview by setting custom view

How to change the height of the tab view manually?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ActionBar.getHeight()` to get the height.

and then to set it to a specific height you can do:

first create a new theme

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>   
    <style name="Theme.FixedSize" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item> 
    </style> 
 </resources>
```

then set the theme to your activity

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.FixedSize"
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/tab_nav</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/tab_nav_text</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">85dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Not working...actionbarsize is only setting height of action bar ,not the height of the tabview ):

Comment: yes to change the height of tabs you need to change height of actionbar  .. check my updated code